# Attaching a common method to multiple object literals

Tags: javascript

I have several objects constructed by object literals:

```
let obj1={
    list: [],
    a() {},
    b() {},
};
let obj2={
    list: [],
    c() {},
    d() {},
};
```

Now I want to attach a common method to all objects, say

```
const f=()=>console.log(this.list);
```

But If I do

```
obj1.f=f; obj2.f=f;
```

And try to run it, it will give `undefined`.

How to do this so that `this` can correspond to the object?

Comment: Use a normal function, not an arrow function.

Comment: You could also extract a method: `const f = { f(){ console.log(this.list); } }.f;`, then assign `[ obj1, obj2 ].forEach((obj) => obj.f = f)`.

Comment: Still doesn't work when using function() {}

Comment: @インターミディエイト Yes, [it does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUjSC.png). Please don’t radically change the question like this.

Comment: That was quick dismissing, a disposable account ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a non-arrow function and then it will work as below:

```js
let obj1={
    list: [],
    a() {},
    b() {},
};
let obj2={
    list: [],
    c() {},
    d() {},
};

const f=function() {console.log(this.list);}
obj1.f=f; 
obj2.f=f;

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2)
```